# Dynamically modifying a winform tab page

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, tabs

I have a set of tab pages for which I need to change the content (controls) at run time. A page might consist of a combo boxes, text boxes, and labels, and I want to replace the whole tab with a single button. What I've read is that the way to do this is to remove the tab page rather than looping over all the controls on the page an setting their visibility, which doesn't work at all. I have the following code:

```
foreach (TabPage t in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    tabControl1.Controls.Remove(t);
}

newPanelButton = new Button();
newPanelButton.Text = "0% Complete";
newPanelButton.Location = new Point(117, 75);
newPanelButton.Height = 80;
newPanelButton.Width = 200;

TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
tabPage.Controls.Add(newPanelButton);

tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage);            

Refresh();
```

This code has no affect whatsoever, as if it is not even there. The existing controls and pages don't change at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked that this code is actually being executed?

Comment: Why are you removing tabpages with 'tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(t);', and adding a tabpage with 'tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage);'? Keep the method of adding/removing a tabpage in sync, would be my first suggestion.

Comment: yes the code is being executed. If I don't remove the tab page what is the way to change the contents of a tab page?

Comment: tabPage.Controls.Clear()

Answer (score 0):

`tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage);`

should be

`tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);`

Comment: this makes no difference. All the existing controls stay on the page, nothing changes. I also tried to set the visibility of all the controls on the page to false. This also does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove/add pages from/to your tabcontrol by using the TabControl.TabPages property.

You code should be (I've shortened it here and there):

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Clear();

var newPanelButton = new Button() {
    Text = "0% Complete",
    Location = new Point(117, 75),
    Height = 80,
    Width = 200
};

var tabPage = new TabPage();
tabPage.Controls.Add(newPanelButton);

tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is running? Or do you have multiple tabcontrols on the form?

Comment: Yes, this is very perplexing. I step through the code in the debugger. This is the only tab control in the application. It seems like nothing I do modifies the content of the page. I may have to try a stand-alone test as a sanity check.